# Navigation Drawer на NavigationView и переносы строк

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Пункт меню, по длине не вмещающийся в экран, NavigationView просто обрезает. Есть ли способ заставить его переносить текст?

Comment: NavigationView отображает ресурс menu ?

Comment: да, NavigationView отображает ресурс menu

Comment: Тогда к сожалению, нет возможности.